# "CMakeLists.txt" seems to be missing

Tags: c++, c, cmake, sfml, 2d-games

I was trying to build SFML in order to start developing 2d-games in c++. I put the source-code directory inside C: (the directory itself is called 'SFML'). while trying to generate .cbp files using CMake, I ran into an error:

**"The source directory "C:/SFML" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt"**

It seems like there is a missing file that CMake didn't create.
I am using Cmake 3.10.1, the installation file can be found in **https://cmake.org/download/** under the title:**"Windows win32-x86 Installer"**.

I tried to build SFML 2.4.2, using the generator of Codeblocks - MinGW makefiles. The version of codeblocks used is: **codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe**, found in **http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26**

Did someone encounter the same problem before and knows how to overcome it? If not -
Is there an already-built, ready to use, libray of this version? (2.4.2)

If not.. do you know about a version of SFML that is usable in visual studio 2017?

And another question *(That is the last one, I promise...)* - maybe you can recommend me about another library for c++, that is usable to develop 2d-games?

edt:
note: I am completely new to all this building thing

the containments of SFML:
[maybe it's the binary version?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNBaR.png)

lib contains some static libraries, bin contains some .dll s

Comment: If `CMakeLists.txt` is not included in the project then you'll need to create it.

Comment: CMakeLists.txt is command file for cmake, it would not create it.

Comment: What makes you think the project uses CMake? It might be using some other build system (but yes, it *does* use cmake). See also: https://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#build-use

Comment: If `CMakeLists.txt` does not exist, then the project is not configured for building with CMake.  (Do not confuse `CMake` with `make` -- they are entirely different things.)

Comment: @JesperJuhl SFML uses CMake as its build system. The script file should be there, unless it's not the complete source repository for some reason.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what's inside "C:\SFML" and the structure of stuff below? This sounds like you might have downloaded a binary build rather than the actual source.

Comment: @Mario I know (I use SFML in several of my own projects) - I was merely trying to get OP to *think* and *not make assumptions* (or at least *explain* any such assumptions in the question).

Comment: What you have on the picture are actually not *source files* but **build files**: file `CMakeCache.txt`, directory `CMakeFiles`. These files are only usable on a machine where they have been created.

Answer (score 3):

You probably downloaded something wrong or potentially extracted the SFML source into a sub folder or something like that.

Since you've mentioned Visual Studio: SFML is 100% compatible with Visual Studio and you can build it from source any time without having to worry about dependencies (everything included in the repository).

The steps to compile are pretty easy. I'd recommend you install [Git](https://git-scm.com/) to clone the latest source from the SFML repository. In addition you'll need *CMake*, which you obviously got already.

- Open a **Command Prompt** and change your directory to `C:\SFML`.
- Clone the official repository using **Git**: `git clone https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git source` (note the trailing .)
- Wait for the source to be checked out to the `source` sub directory.
- Create a new directory called `build`: `md build && cd build`
- Now invoke **CMake**, pointing to the source directory and also defining your install path: `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/SFML ../source`
- Build and install a debug build of SFML: `cmake --build . --target install --config debug`
- Build and install a release build of SFML: `cmake --build . --target install --config release`
- Alternatively you can just open the generated Visual Studio solution and build the `INSTALL` project on your own.

(You shouldn't have to define a build tool or anything; CMake should notice Visual Studio being installed and pick it up automatically.)

Comment: Or use the CMake GUI tool and select Visual Studio from the list of available generators. https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/compile-with-cmake.php

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this using cmake version 3.10 when using the -S command line option.  On cmake version 3.15.4 it behaves as expected - so if you update cmake then it might just work.

Note that the -S command line option was not supported before version 3.13:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/release/3.13.html#command-line

Normally cmake is called from a "build" subdirectory of a project root, the project root contains CMakelists.txt.  So you would create a "build" directory, change to it, and submit "cmake ..".  This would pull in CMakelists.txt from the project root, and use the "build" subdirectory that you are in as the build directory.  We say "build", what it actually does is generate makefiles  which can then used by the "native" build system (e.g. "make" or Visual Studio) to perform the actual compilation and linking.  This arrangement is not always convenient, hence the introduction of the -S and -B command line options.